# Move cells to new column at each 48th row

Tags: r, excel, row

I have list with names in A1:A144 and I want to move A49:A96 to B1:B48 and A97:144 to C1:C48.

So for each 48th row, I want the next 48 rows moved to a new column.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to consider a VBA alternative then:

```
Sub MoveData()
    nF = 1
    nL = 48
    nSize = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    nBlock = nSize / nL
    For k = 1 To nBlock
        nF = nF + 48
        nL = nL + 48
        Range("A" & nF & ":A" & nL).Copy Cells(1, k + 1)
        Range("A" & nF & ":A" & nL).ClearContents
    Next k
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how scalable this solution is, but it does work.

First let's pretend your names are `x` and you want the solution to be in `new.df`

```
number.shifts <- ceiling(length(x) / 48) # work out how many columns we need

# create an empty (NA) data frame with the dimensions we need
new.df <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = length(x), ncol = number.shifts) 

# run a for-loop over the x, shift the column over every 48th row
j <- 1
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (i %% 48 == 0) {j <- j + 1}
  new.df[i,j] <- x[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to elaborate on your question a little more. Do you have the data in R or in Excel and do you want the output to be in R or in Excel?

That beeing said, if `x` is your vector indicating clusters

```
x <- rep(1:3, each = 48)
```

and `y` is the variable containing names or whatever that you want to distribute over columns A:C (each having 48 rows),

```
y <- sample(letters, 3 * 48, replace = TRUE)
```

you can do this:

```
y.wide <- do.call(cbind, split(y, x))
```

Comment: I want to use R, its for later correlation analyses, but anything works! :)

Comment: @user2862862: well, u have couple of working solutions here (R and VBA). You might consider marking one of them as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just as there is `stack` in R to create a very long representation of a group of columns, there is `unstack` to take a long column and make it into a wide form.

Here's a basic example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = 1:144)
mydf$groups <- paste0("A", gl(n=3, k=48))  ## One of many ways to create groups
mydf2 <- unstack(mydf)
head(mydf2)
#   A1 A2  A3
# 1  1 49  97
# 2  2 50  98
# 3  3 51  99
# 4  4 52 100
# 5  5 53 101
# 6  6 54 102
tail(mydf2)
#    A1 A2  A3
# 43 43 91 139
# 44 44 92 140
# 45 45 93 141
# 46 46 94 142
# 47 47 95 143
# 48 48 96 144
```